# Transverse open book decompositions supporting the same contact structure

Tags: 3-manifolds, contact-topology

An  [open book decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_book_decomposition?wprov=sfti1) on an oriented 3-manifold $M$ is a fibered oriented link $B\subset M$, bounding a foliation by Seifert surfaces $\Sigma_t \subset M$, $t\in S^1$, $\partial \Sigma_t = B$.

A contact form is a 1-form $\alpha \in \Omega^1(M)$ such that $\alpha \wedge d\alpha > 0$. Then the open book $\Sigma_t$ supports the contact form $\alpha$ if $\alpha_{| B} > 0$ and $d\alpha_{| \Sigma_t-B} > 0$. [Thurston and Winkelnkemper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1975-052-01/S0002-9939-1975-0375366-7/S0002-9939-1975-0375366-7.pdf) showed that an open book supports a unique contact form, and it is known conversely that every contact form is supported by an open book, unique up to plumbing or deplumbing by positive Hopf bands; this is known as the [Giroux correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_book_decomposition?wprov=sfti1).

My question is whether given two open books $(B, \Sigma_t), (C, \Gamma_t)$ supporting the contact form $\alpha$, can we contact isotope $(C, \Gamma)$ to $(C’,\Gamma’)$ (so that it still supports $\alpha$ throughout the isotopy) so that $C’$ is transverse to $\Sigma_t$ and $B$ is transverse to $\Gamma’_t$?

By a [result of Elena Pavelescu](https://msp.org/pjm/2011/253-2/p10.xhtml), we know that we can do either one individually; the question is whether we can achieve this simultaneously? I don’t know how to do this even for the standard tight contact form on $S^3$.